# VS Code - Golang "go module packages.Load error"

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code, linux-mint, go-modules

### Backstory

I got this error amongst numerous others setting up a new virtual box LMDE5 on my new windows 11 pro computer. I haven't used windows in about 12 years, and the changes were crazy causing countless errors on Windows and LMDE5 Vbox.
My last issue was this in vs code.

### Error

```golang
go module packages.Load error: err: exit status 2: stderr: go: no such tool "compile": go list
```

### My project directory structure

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── project.code-workspace
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── sub_packages
    ├── backend
    │   ├── folder1
    │   ├── folder2
    ├── api
    │   ├── handlers
    │   └── requests
    ├── entities
    ├── services
    └── utils
```

### settings.json file

```json
{
    // ...
    "go.goroot": "/usr/local/go",
    "go.gopath": "/home/user_name/go",
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Add the go tool dir ENV variable directly to VS Code `settings.json` to the settings to pickup the location of the folder `.../linux_amd64` where compile was located.

### settings.json file

```json
{
    // ...
    "go.goroot": "/usr/local/go",
    "go.gopath": "/home/username/go",
    "go.alternateTools": {
        "GOTOOLDIR": "/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"    
    },
    // ...
}
```